# Differences Nullable values: .Value or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, null, nullable, non-nullable

I'm kinda new to Nullable. I have a DateTime in C# that I want to be null, than assign the value in a try-catch, and after that check whether it's null or not.

Code:

```
DateTime? dt = null;
try
{
    dt = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
catch(FormatException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The given string is not valid and could not be converter to a DateTime");
}
// Check if the DateTime is not null
// If it's not null, do something with the DateTime
```

So, my question:

Which of the two should I use, WHY should I use it, and what are the differences between the both:

```
if(dt != null)
{
    doSomethingWithDateTime(dt);
}
```

Or:

```
if(dt.HasValue)
{
    doSomethingWithDateTime(dt.Value);
}
```

Comment: How is `doSomethingWithDateTime` defined? I ask because if it is defined as taking `DateTime`, the first alternative won't even compile. Note that checking for `!= null` and `.HasValue` amounts to the same thing, the first will be autoconverted to the other.

Comment: `dt` is `DateTime?` but `dt.Value` is `DateTime`. That depends on your `doSomethingWithDateTime` implementation. Other that that, checking is `null` or not and using `.HasValue` is the same AFAIK.

Comment: @Sayse You're wrong, if it is a nullable value (like in this question), it will.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - Yeah I went and double checked straight after posting that

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks, this is the answer to my question. If you want you can post an answer I can accept, or should I do it myself and credit you? Your call.

Comment: Since it has been flagged as a duplicate, no more answers are accepted (and possibly not necessary).